# Why is my apache Directory config being ignored?

Tags: apache

I have sections of several sites IP restricted using a Directory match rule. Now, I want to allow a new IP have access to just one of those sites.

The secured folders are an admin directoy (always `/admin`), a few random secure folders and WordPress admin areas if that site happens to have a blog. They `<Directory ~>` directive is as follows:

```
<Directory ~ "^/var/www/vhosts/[^/]+/public/((securefolder1)|(securefolder2)|((blog/)?wp\-)?admin)">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333
</Directory>
```

I tried to allow the new IP address to a specific WordPress admin area by adding this directive after the above one:

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/foo.com/public/wp-admin">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333 444.444.444.444
</Directory>
```

Although the original IPs still work, the new IP is still blocked from viewing. I was wondering if it was to do with [the order they are merged in](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin), so I changed `<Directory>` to `<Directory ~>` for the foo.com directive but it still doesn't work. I also tried moving it to come *after* the other directive with no effect.

**How can I override the IP restriction for this one site?**

**Note:** `.htaccess` solutions are acceptable if that's possible.

*Apache version is 2.2.15*

Comment: Is it the same if you put the directive before the original one?

Comment: @Juan Yes. I've put it before and after. I've also tried with `Directory` instead of `Directory ~` before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is a merge order issue

Just as you suspected, it DOES have "to do with the order they are merged in."

> processed in the order shortest directory component to longest. So for example, `<Directory /var/web/dir>` will be processed before `<Directory /var/web/dir/subdir>`.

- [See Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin)

### Use the Apache merge order *carefully*

If you take a second look at those docs, you'll notice:

> The order of merging is:
>
> 1. `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and `.htaccess` done simultaneously (with `.htaccess`, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)
> 2. `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory ~>`)
> 3. `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done simultaneously
> 4. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously

### ...Which means you can do any one of a number of things:

1. Create the `foo.com` Directory entry as a Directory Match
2. Adjust the Directory paths (with some clever regex) such that the `foo.com` entry is LONGER than the main entry.
3. Define access with Files or Location entries (a little trickier, but still doable.

### For your case, it may be as simple as:

```
# regex not allowed here, adjust accordingly (three separate directory entries)
<Directory "^/var/www/vhosts/[^/]+/public/((securefolder1)|(securefolder2)|((blog/)?wp\-)?admin)">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333
</Directory>

<Directory ~ "/var/www/vhosts/foo.com/public/wp-admin">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333 444.444.444.444
</Directory>
```

### Improved solution

```
# This should be reflective of the url
<Location ~ "^/((securefolder1)|(securefolder2)|((blog/)?wp\-)?admin)">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333
</Location>

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/foo.com/public/wp-admin">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222 333.333.333.333 444.444.444.444
</Directory>
```

Note, if these are shared servers, an users are allowed to write their own `.htaccess` file, that COULD override the Location directive by changing the url to access the files. In such a case the only remaining solutions are the previous `<Directory>` example, or using VHosts directives.

Comment: Fantastic. I've used your suggestion of `Directory` followed by `Directory ~` and it works a treat. Your answer helps make more sense of the docs. Which, interestingly, made this more prominent: `Sections inside <VirtualHost> sections are applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.` So, if I'd have put any `Directory`/`Directory ~` in the virtual host instead of `httpd.conf` would that work?

Comment: Of course! The only catch is that if there are multiple vHosts, you'd have to define the additional ip access for every one.

Comment: Also of note, is combining http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include with the http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define directive. It's been a while since I've done it, but you should be able to include a file which `Define whitelist_internal 11.11 22.22` then include it and `Allow from ${whitelist_internal}`

Comment: I may have been eager in my excitement... it *seems* that anyone can access the `/admin`/`wp-admin`/`securefolderX` folders with this configuration. Did you happy to test your config or was it a "should work"?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find in the docs where you can use regex without `~` or `DirectoryMatch`?

Comment: I wasn't trying to write your whole directive, but you are correct, you could not use regex with that solution. It would require more specific configuration.

I'll adjust my answer to provide you solution using Location (I honestly think that would be much easier)